# matplotlib loop make subplot for each category

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to write a loop that will make  a figure with 25 subplots, 1 for each country. My code makes a figure with 25 subplots, but the plots are empty. What can I change to make the data appear in the graphs?

```
fig = plt.figure()

for c,num in zip(countries, xrange(1,26)):
    df0=df[df['Country']==c]
    ax = fig.add_subplot(5,5,num)
    ax.plot(x=df0['Date'], y=df0[['y1','y2','y3','y4']], title=c)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You got confused between the matplotlib plotting function and the pandas plotting wrapper.
The problem you have is that `ax.plot` does not have any `x` or `y` argument.

#### Use `ax.plot`

In that case, call  it like `ax.plot(df0['Date'], df0[['y1','y2']])`, without `x`, `y` and `title`. Possibly set the title separately.
Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

countries = np.random.choice(list("ABCDE"),size=25)
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date" : range(200),
                    'Country' : np.repeat(countries,8),
                    'y1' : np.random.rand(200),
                    'y2' : np.random.rand(200)})

fig = plt.figure()

for c,num in zip(countries, xrange(1,26)):
    df0=df[df['Country']==c]
    ax = fig.add_subplot(5,5,num)
    ax.plot(df0['Date'], df0[['y1','y2']])
    ax.set_title(c)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Use the pandas plotting wrapper

In this case plot your data via `df0.plot(x="Date",y =['y1','y2'])`.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

countries = np.random.choice(list("ABCDE"),size=25)
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date" : range(200),
                    'Country' : np.repeat(countries,8),
                    'y1' : np.random.rand(200),
                    'y2' : np.random.rand(200)})

fig = plt.figure()

for c,num in zip(countries, xrange(1,26)):
    df0=df[df['Country']==c]
    ax = fig.add_subplot(5,5,num)
    df0.plot(x="Date",y =['y1','y2'], title=c, ax=ax, legend=False)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How would I add a single legend at the bottom of the whole figure?

Comment: For adding a legend, I would like to refer you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/4124317), since this is probably out of the scope of this question here.

Comment: For those using Python 3, you need to change `xrange` into `range`.

Answer (score 6):

I don't remember that well how to use original subplot system but you seem to be rewriting the plot. In any case you should take a look at [gridspec](https://matplotlib.org/api/gridspec_api.html). Check the following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure()

gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(5, 5)
countries = ["Country " + str(i) for i in range(1, 26)]
axs = []
for c, num in zip(countries, range(1,26)):
    axs.append(fig.add_subplot(gs1[num - 1]))
    axs[-1].plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])

plt.show()
```

Which results in this:

[image: matplotlib gridspec example]

Just replace the example with your data and it should work fine.

**NOTE**: I've noticed you are using `xrange`. I've used `range` because my version of Python is 3.x. Adapt to your version.

Comment: it'd be more pythonic/idiomatic + future/backwards compatible to use `for num, c in enumerate(countries, 1):`