# Pandas Python: Put For Loop Created Graphs into 5 Row 3 Column Subplots

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, matplotlib

Right now my code looks like this:

```
for i in range(len(frames)):
label = labels[i]
frame = frames[i]
plt.plot( 1/frame['Temperature(K)'], frame['Resistivity'], label=label)
plt.title('Inverse Temperature vs. Resistivity' +' '+ str( label))
plt.xlabel('Inverse Temperature') 
plt.ylabel('Resistivity')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This results in 15 separate plots. How do I adjust this for loop to get these plots into a 5 row 3 column subplot structure?

Comment: Doe, please check this: Hope it helps!
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46713186/matplotlib-loop-make-subplot-for-each-category)

Comment: Thank you so much Priya!